# How to configure Apache 2.4 to use WebWockets using Node.js Express and Socket.IO?

Tags: apache, express, websocket, socket.io

We are configuring a bot application which uses Socket.IO (WebSockets) to connect to a Node.js Express server which sits behind Apache 2.4.

We need to configure a reverse proxy to be able to communicate from the chat application to the Express server. We have tried the follwing configurations but we have had no success as yet:

1. ```
   <Location /globalsalesreporting_bot/>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/globalsalesreporting_bot/socket.io            [NC]
       RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
       RewriteRule "^/globalsalesreporting_bot/socket.io"           "wss://10.11.74.4:4010/socket.io/" [P,L]

       ProxyPass https://10.11.74.4:4010/
       ProxyPassReverse https://10.11.74.4:4010/
   </Location>
   ```
2. ```
   ProxyPass "/XXX_bot/" "https://10.11.74.4:4010/XXX_bot/"
   ProxyPassReverse "/XXX_bot/" "https://10.11.74.4:4010/XXX_bot/"
   ```
3. ```
   ProxyPass /socket.io/ https://10.11.74.4:4010/socket.io/
   ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ https://10.11.74.4:4010/socket.io/
   ```

Can some one guide to the correct steps or tutorial to configure Apache for using WebSockets?

Comment: Why are you putting Express behind Apache?

Comment: Organization policy, all HTTP traffic has to go through Apache. Hence Apache will play the role of a reverse proxy